# Adding VRT file to QGIS project

Tags: qgis, import, vrt, qgs

I've created a *.vrt* file through a text editor. Trying to add it to a project has me baffled.

Comment: On Windows10/QGIS 3.12 CTRL+SHIFT+R >triple dots< select *.vrt

Comment: Do you have raster or vector VRT? Verify that VRT is OK with gdalinfo or ogrinfo and then just add as a new raster of vector layer as any other spatial file.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a vector, then just click on add vector then choose vrt from the file list:

[image]

Do the same if it is a raster by clicking on add new raster.

[image]

Another way would be simply by dragging and dropping the file into the view or accessing it through the browser panel and drop it on the view.

If none of the above work then the file might be corrupted perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the file has an error... Thought I was just loading it the wrong way...

Comment: update us when you succeed @GeoJim !

Comment: Hi @GeoJim! Did you find a solution? Because in my case, I have an .vrt file that have sent me, but I can't open it. I think this line in my file is an error: <VRTDataset rasterXSize="0" rasterYSize="0">.